# Is there an updated (non-Nmap) top 100 or top 1000 common ports list?

Tags: nmap, ports, network-scanners

I know Nmap has nmap-services file which gives us the list of top 1000 ports/services found on the Internet. But this list seems to be outdated, as the Nmap top 1000 list doesn't include several services used now-a-days (like 27017/mongoDB, 6379/redis, 11211/memcached, etc). Is there any source other than Nmap, which can provide the updated list of top 1000 common ports/services used in the Internet?

Comment: Do you need the top 1000, or will [all of them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_TCP_and_UDP_port_numbers) suffice?

Comment: As you may see on [this service file history](https://github.com/nmap/nmap/commits/master/nmap-services) it is updated by upstream. Consider forking and creating a pull request if you think that some ports may be added.

Comment: Need the Top 1000 ports